# Congruences in cyclotomic integer ring

Tags: number-theory

Let $\mathbf{Z}[\omega]$ be the ring of integers of the cyclotomic field $\mathbf{Q}(\omega)$ where $\omega^p=1$ and $p$ is an odd prime. Let $I=(1-\omega)$ be the prime ideal in $\mathbf{Z}[\omega]$ above $p$ generated by $1-\omega$.

I'd like to determine whether the following congruence 
$X^p\equiv a\,mod\,I^n$
is solvable for any integer $a$ and any natural number $n$.

I thought of the following strategy, but I am not sure if it's correct.

Consider the ring homomorphism $f:\mathbf{Z}[\omega]/I^n\rightarrow\mathbf{Z}[\omega]/I^n$ given by $f(x\,mod\,I^n)=x^p\,mod\,I^n$. 
The generators of $\mathbf{Z}[\omega]/I^n$ are sent to $1\,mod\,I^n$ in $\mathbf{Z}[\omega]/I^n$. So the image of $f$ is $\mathbf{Z}\,mod\,I^n$. Therefore, any element $a\,mod\,I^n$ with $a$ an integer has a preimage under $f$, so the above congruence is solvable for any integer $a$ and natural number $n$.

I'm not sure about this proof, I would appreciate some feedback from the math stack exchange community. Thanks!